# jqplot date axis from timestamp

Tags: date, timestamp, axis, jqplot

I'm trying to get a x-axis with dates on it. The x data is a timestamp. Somehow I can't get it right.

The line has values like:

```
line = [[1334856823000, 2], [1334856853000, 1], [1334856883000, 0], [1334856913000,4],[1334856914000, 13], [1334856943000, 16], [1334856973000, 23], [1334857003000, 24], [1334857033000, 36], [1334857063000, 14], [1334857093000, 1]]

            $.jqplot('container', [line],
              { title: "Snelheidsgrafiek",
                axes: {
                  xaxis: {
                    rederer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {tickRenderer: $.jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer},
                    tickOptions: {formatString: '%H:%M'}
                  },
                  yaxis: {
                    min: 0
                  }
                }
            });
```

Now it displays just `%H:%M` as the label.
I tried many variations, but can't get it going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it goes.
Your problem is that the `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer` should be on the same level as `renderer`, and not inside `rendererOptions`.

[Please see the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/DWFTb/)

**EDIT**

Also you are missing an import of `CanvasTextRenderer` which the `CanvasAxisTickRenderer` uses and you forget to start with a capital letter `C`, like so: `$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer`.

Comment: Thx, but..damn, can't get it going... I see it working in the jsfiddle, even with the whole line array in it. I copied the code and the script tags, but it still displays '%H:%M'. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Take a look at the Firebug console. See if you get some meaningful errors there. Also please let me know what you are exactly importing (i.e. what scripts you use and how you add them to your page).

Comment: I use jQuery 1.6.4, I've dowloaded the latest zip (version 1.0.0b2-r1012) and used the tree minified files.
I moved everything to a test server and now it works, although the scaling (min and max value of the x-axis is still weird. I'll send you a link

Comment: http://freetrack.abx314.nl/tracks/view_plot/a7834d0c21e1efaffc0ef3e214c12477fd4ec0faaf91993e945ec562fd2e1164
Here you can see the problem. For other tracks the whole graph only apears on the right side of the cavas. So somehow it makes the x-axis much bigger than it needs to be.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**. I have noticed some bugs in your code, e.g. you were missing import of CanvasTextRenderer and class name should start from capital letter.

Comment: I added the TextRenderer with no effect. Changing to a capital c breaks the graph (also in the JS fiddle)

Comment: Please see me code jsfiddle it now has them all there and it must be capital letter `C` http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/DWFTb/  Please link me to your problem again after you make the suggested corrections.

Comment: OK, I've added the script tags as you gave them. And now it works, see link above) I'm not sure about the difference with the ones I donwloaded (are they not updates anymore, they date from 2011-11-12??) One difference I noticed is that in the DOM inspector I could see that the config.pluginLocation and config.srcLocation were set wrong. Those keys don't exist when loading the js remotely. Is there somekind of setup file I missed?

Comment: No I do not think that there is a setup file. I just downloaded my cop[y of `jqPlot` and used it with the newest version of `jQuery` and all was always fine. Try maybe updating jQuery, I have noticed you were using 1.6. Otherwise try a very fresh download of jqPlot. I understands this sorts out your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try. this is copied in a hurry out of a working code. I stripped out a lot to give you a better overview. Maybe it is missing a bracket here and there but it should give you an idea of what to set up and how the affected variables. This works 100% for sure.

Make sure to include the needed Javascript libraries aswell.

If you need more details, let me know...

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function($) {
            var indizes;
            var plot1; 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                   $(document).ready(function() {
indizes = [["2011-12-31",0.00],["2012-01-31",6.25],["2012-02-28",12.56],["2012-03-31",17.62],["2012-04-30",18.72],["2012-05-31",12.44],["2012-06-30",15.14],["2012-07-31",20.27],["2012-08-31",20.82],["2012-09-30",24.47],["2012-10-31",25.68],["2012-11-30",26.41],["2012-12-31",28.43],["2013-01-31",32.76],["2013-02-28",36.82],["2013-03-31",42.29],["2013-04-30",43.14],["2013-05-31",45.87],["2013-06-30",40.68],["2013-07-31",50.58],["2013-08-31",46.00],["2013-09-29",56.20],["2013-10-02",55.40]];                            ;

            draw_first();

            function draw_first() {
                plot1 = $.jqplot("chartdiv", [indizes], {
                    seriesColors: ["rgba(0, 189, 255, 1)"],
                    title: '',
                    grid: {
                        background: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.0)',
                        drawBorder: false,
                        shadow: false,
                        gridLineColor: '#333',
                        gridLineWidth: 1
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: true,
                        placement: 'inside',
                        location: 'nw'
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        rendererOptions: {
                            smooth: false,
                            animation: {
                                show: true
                            }
                        },
                        showMarker: true,
                        pointLabels: {show: pointlabels},
                        markerOptions: {
                            style: 'filledSquare'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            label: 'Indizes'
                        }
                    ],
                    axesDefaults: {
                        rendererOptions: {
                            baselineWidth: 2,
                            baselineColor: '#444444',
                            drawBaseline: false
                        }
                    },
                    axes: {
                        xaxis: {
                            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                            tickOptions: {
                                formatString: "%b",
                                angle: 0,
                                textColor: '#888'
                            },
                            min: "2012-10-01",
                            max: "2013-10-31",
                            tickInterval: "1 month",
                            drawMajorGridlines: true
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                            pad: 0,
                            rendererOptions: {
                                minorTicks: 1
                            },
                            drawMajorGridlines: false,
                            tickOptions: {
                                formatString: function() {
                                    return '%#.1f %';
                                }(),
                                showMark: false,
                                textColor: '#888'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } 

        })(jQuery);</script>
```